# std::ifstream read 32 bits at a time

Tags: c++

I want to know why, with a stringstream  the distance is as expected. The iterators iterate over 32 bits at a time, and I get 6.

But with ifstream templated on char32_t I was expecting it to read 4 bytes at a time, but it seems inside streambuf it will read a single char, then just cast this to char32_t. So distance is 24.

The file test.txt contains the same "abcdef" saved as utf32 little endian with no bom. available [here](https://files.fm/down.php?cf&i=43rrw2af&n=test.txt)

Why is this? Why does a std::basic_ifstream not get read 32 bits at a time when using a std::istreambuf_iterator. If this is just going to read a char perform a cast to char32_t, what is the point of the template parameter and how can I read a file 32 bits at a time with std::istreambuf_iterator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>

int main() {
    std::basic_string<char32_t> str = U"abcdef";
    std::basic_stringstream<char32_t> data{ str };

    //std::basic_ifstream<char32_t> data("test.txt", std::ios::binary);

    size_t dist = std::distance(std::istreambuf_iterator<char32_t>(data), std::istreambuf_iterator<char32_t>());

    std::cout << dist << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, your question boils down to two issues:

- What is the difference between a stringstream and a filestream?
- Why does a uint32_t-parametrized filestream still read single bytes?

Both of these is explained with the so-called encoding, represented in streams by their `codecvt` (code conversion) facet. This facet is responsible for translating external bytes to an in-memory representation and vice-versa. The default facet will just convert one internal element to one external byte, hence the one-to-one relation between bytes and characters. In order to read the file in chunks of four bytes, you need to `imbue()` the stream with a UCS4 or UTF-32 codeconversion facet.

For stringstreams, you don't specify an external sequence but an internal one, so no code conversion takes place.

Comment: That's great. My only question with this is if it was arbitrary binary data, ie potentially the values are not valid UTF-32 codepoints, but I still wanted to read as 32 bits at a time. It doesn't appear that that the locale's available support a 'dumb' read 32bits at a time -> https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/locale. Presumably std::codecvt will do some checking on the data.